How to handle empty string for populated fields
what are the possibles operation that I can do for handle empty string for populated fields ?
due to some mistakes populated fields are store as empty string and I don't know how many populated fields store as empty string
because I have big database with more than 2,00000 records for every model in mongoDB with node.js
When I try to query for that document I got this error and due to business logic I need to display that documents also so I cannot pass that key as condition like this
const result = await Model.find({rpc_id: {$ne: ''}})

Something went wrong in paginateData method with error: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "" (type string) at path "_id" for model "rpc_credentials" error
[Caller: postMerchantTransactionList] : [24/4/2024, 9:40:22 am 93] : error :  CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "" (type string) at path "_id" for model "rpc_credentials"
    at SchemaObjectId.cast (/var/www/html/coinremmiter-admin/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/objectId.js:250:11)
    at SchemaType.applySetters (/var/www/html/coinremmiter-admin/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schemaType.js:1221:12)
    at SchemaType.castForQuery (/var/www/html/coinremmiter-admin/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schemaType.js:1636:17)
    at /var/www/html/coinremmiter-admin/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schemaType.js:1597:18
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at SchemaObjectId.handle$in (/var/www/html/coinremmiter-admin/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schemaType.js:1593:14)
    at SchemaType.castForQuery (/var/www/html/coinremmiter-admin/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schemaType.js:1632:20)
    at cast (/var/www/html/coinremmiter-admin/node_modules/mongoose/lib/cast.js:352:39)
    at Query.cast (/var/www/html/coinremmiter-admin/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4778:12)
    at Query._castConditions (/var/www/html/coinremmiter-admin/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2199:10) {
  stringValue: '""',
  messageFormat: undefined,
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: '',
  path: '_id',
  reason: BSONError: input must be a 24 character hex string, 12 byte Uint8Array, or an integer
      at new ObjectId (/var/www/html/coinremmiter-admin/node_modules/bson/lib/bson.cjs:2288:23)
      at castObjectId (/var/www/html/coinremmiter-admin/node_modules/mongoose/lib/cast/objectid.js:25:12)
      at SchemaObjectId.cast (/var/www/html/coinremmiter-admin/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/objectId.js:248:12)
      at SchemaType.applySetters (/var/www/html/coinremmiter-admin/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schemaType.js:1221:12)
      at SchemaType.castForQuery (/var/www/html/coinremmiter-admin/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schemaType.js:1636:17)
      at /var/www/html/coinremmiter-admin/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schemaType.js:1597:18
      at Array.map (<anonymous>)
      at SchemaObjectId.handle$in (/var/www/html/coinremmiter-admin/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schemaType.js:1593:14)
      at SchemaType.castForQuery (/var/www/html/coinremmiter-admin/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schemaType.js:1632:20)
      at cast (/var/www/html/coinremmiter-admin/node_modules/mongoose/lib/cast.js:352:39),
  valueType: 'string',
  model: Model { rpc_credentials }
}

So what should I do now
I want to store null value for all populated fields which store empty string
I am using mongoose version
@8.2.2
and my schema is something look like this
const TransactionSchema = new Schema({
    wallet_id: { type: String },
    coin_id: { type: String },
    rpc_id: { type: String },
    __v: { type: Number, select: false }
}, { timestamps: true, strict: false });

TransactionSchema.virtual(
    "rpc", // can be any name for your virtual, used as key to populate
    {
        ref: "rpc_credentials",
        localField: "rpc_id", // name of field in transaction's schema
        foreignField: "_id",
    }
)

rpc_credentials schema
    const rpcCredencialSchema = new Schema({
    rpcConnected: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    __v: { type: Number, select: false }
}, { timestamps: true, strict: false });


"When I try to query for that document I got this error and due to business logic I need to display that documents also so I cannot pass that key as condition like this" - Which is the conditional you can pass as per the business logic? The question is otherwise it is going to retrieve all. That is also fine, but to understand it, this is being asked.

Which is the version of mongoose used? Please post the schema definition as well.

I am using mongoose 8.2.2 version
and mongoDB version v7.0.2

To debug, can you please update your post by including the schema definition of Model.?

Is the issue still persisting ?

Yes still his issue occurs

It seems the issue is from the virtual rpc. Can you please brief the collection rpc_credentails referenced here.

Please post the schema definition of rpc_credentials as well.

Sure I will post

Try it!
const result = await Model.find({ rpc_id: { $ne: null } });

No I want to update it's value
